# I can't download Firefox, just Aurora

Tags: 11.10, firefox

I try to install Firefox, but it just gives me an Aurora. I tried:
I have tried to install Firefox, but I have only been able to get Aurora.

I tried the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I want to remove Aurora and install Firefox, what else can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to uninstall Aurora, and then install Firefox via the command line (`sudo apt-get install firefox`). What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: How can I delete Aurora? 11.10

Comment: In the Software Center, find Aurora and click on `Remove`

Comment: @WolterHellmund: And try to install Firefox again? Will my history disappear? Thank you.

Comment: In linux your browsing history and other application data is saved to your home directory automatically and not removed unless the application is _purged_ (which you have to use the command `sudo apt-get remove some-package --purge` for) so yes, don't worry your history will still be browsable.

It doesn't matter whether you install Firefox after or before you remove Aurora, as they are different applications and one action will not interfere with the other, so go ahead!

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric)**  (*not tested for other releases*)

INSTALL/REMOVE Aurora (Mozilla alpha-releases)

install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/thunderbird-aurora

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

downgrade

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge      (ONLY if required)

sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/thunderbird-aurora
```